# Sorting rows in entity based on attribute in core data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am having problem with my core data's entity. It has three attributes similar to this table

```
Name         value      details 

cat           xxx         01
apple         YYY         10
ball          ZZZ         11
```

I need to sort the table based on attribute "Name" to make the entity look like this

```
Name         value      details 

apple         YYY         10
ball          ZZZ         11
cat           xxx         01
```

Using the below code only sorts the "name" attribute values, but i need the entire row to be sorted.

```
  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest1 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UserData"];
       fetchRequest1.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    [fetchRequest1 setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"userName", nil]];
    fetchRequest1.returnsDistinctResults = YES;


    NSArray *dictionaries1 = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:nil];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"userName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray* sortedArray=[dictionaries1 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

Is there a way to sort the entire row and save the entity ??

Comment: Heh? Whats the objects that has name, value and details property.

Comment: username ,uservalue and userdetails

Comment: Core data like SQL. If you want to store something about a user, you create a SINGLE core data object called User (like a table in SQL), which has 3 properties. Try looking at a core data tutorial to understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified `NSDictionaryResultType`, so the fetch returns only the one attribute that you specify - `username`.  To fetch the complete object, with all its attributes, delete those lines.  You also don't need `returnsDistinctResults`.  And you might as well get the fetch to do the sorting, rather than sorting the array afterwards:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest1 = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UserData"];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"userName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
fetchRequest1.sortDescriptors = @[sort];
NSArray *sortedResults = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest1 error:nil];
```